# How to write last string value to next rows which contains null

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table as like below

```
person_id   event_time
aba         2021-09-10 10:00:00
finix       2021-09-10 10:30:35
walter      2021-09-10 10:35:24
cimon       2021-09-10 10:36:48
null        null
null        null
abhijit    2021-09-10 11:35:00
ankur      2021-09-10 14:30:35
```

I want to replace the null values with the previous not null values
like as below

```
person_id   event_time
    aba         2021-09-10 10:00:00
    finix       2021-09-10 10:30:35
    walter      2021-09-10 10:35:24
    cimon       2021-09-10 10:36:48
    cimon       2021-09-10 10:36:48
    cimon       2021-09-10 10:36:48
    abhijit     2021-09-10 11:35:00
    ankur       2021-09-10 14:30:35
```

how to achieve this in big query, please help

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as a "previous" row unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the previous row identifier field to order or aggregate so that you can later use it to order (or apply partition by) with [last_value](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#last_value) operator

```
WITH
  table_data AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS row_,
    'aba' AS person_id,
    '2021-09-10 10:00:00' AS event_time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    2 AS row_,
    'finix' AS person_id,
    '2021-09-10 10:30:35' AS event_time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    3 AS row_,
    'walter' AS person_id,
    '2021-09-10 10:35:24' AS event_time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    4 AS row_,
    'cimon' AS person_id,
    '2021-09-10 10:36:48' AS event_time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    5 AS row_,
    NULL AS person_id,
    NULL AS event_time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    6 AS row_,
    NULL AS person_id,
    NULL AS event_time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    7 AS row_,
    'abhijit' AS person_id,
    '2021-09-10 11:35:00' AS event_time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    8 AS row_,
    'ankur' AS person_id,
    '2021-09-10 14:30:35' AS event_time )
SELECT
  row_,
  person_id,
  event_time,
  LAST_VALUE(person_id IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY row_ RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS person_id_new,
  LAST_VALUE(event_time IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY row_ RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS event_time_new,
FROM
  table_data
```

Result:

[image]